# Why in a IPV4 packet, checksum is calculated against the IP header and not the entire packet like transport protocols tcp/udp?

Tags: ipv4

Why in a IPV4 packet, checksum is calculated against the IP header and not on the data like transport protocols tcp/udp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a matter of speed: the Internet backbone routers direct millions of packets per second and calculating a checksum over the entire contents would drastically slow down the packet processing.

The IPv6 specification [removes even the header checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Simplified_processing_by_routers) to allow routers to route packets even faster. (It's just one of many steps IPv6 has taken to reduce the amount of time routers must inspect every packet. It all adds up.) Discarding corrupted packets is now placed entirely on end nodes.

Comment: Thank you. In IPV6, the end systems will be responsible for fragmentation and reassembling of packets so that the routers do not undergo this process.

Comment: Does that mean that TCP is slower as checksum for TCP/UDP packets are calculated on data and header?

Comment: Yes, TCP packets are slower to handle than raw IP packets due to the checksumming. However, they are slower _on the endpoints_, rather than on the core routers, and as a result the slowdown is a lot easier to tolerate. (Some NICs have on-board checksum support to offload the work from the CPU, but those aren't always faster...)

Comment: "Discarding corrupted packets is now placed entirely on end nodes." Does this mean if an intermediate router gets a corrupted IPv4 packet with wrong check-sum, the router will not discard it?

Comment: @vincentmathew: sorry, I don't know how IPv4 routers work in practice. I presume some will drop the packet (I know I've configured firewalls to do this) and I presume some high-traffic routers will pass them through, just on grounds that making decisions takes time that high-throughput routers do not have.

Answer (score 5):

There are two good reasons for this.

**First,** all higher-level protocols that encapsulate data in the IPv4
datagram have a checksum field that covers the whole packet. Therefore, the checksum
for the IPv4 datagram does not have to check the encapsulated data.

**Second,** the header of the IPv4 packet changes with each visited router, but the data do not. So the checksum
includes only the part that has changed. If the data were included, each router must recalculate the checksum for the whole packet, which means an increase in processing time.

source: *Data Communications and Networking* by Behrouz A. Forouzan

Answer (score 4):

Ipv4 ensures only the address is correct ,so it calculates the checksum using only the address and not using the data,ensuring reliable transfer of data is not the network layer's job